# Go target language

Tags: go, output

What is the Go language compiled to? Nobody seems to want to write it anywhere on the net. I am searching for the target language. I am thinking it's probably assembly, C, or relocatable machine code?

Comment: That answers how the run-time is implemented, not the target code - there is a big difference. The run-time is how the target code is executed. The target code is what the code is compiled to. Example Java compiles to .class files(the target code), but the run-time is the Java Virtual Machine, which interprets the target code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference implementation compiles Go to native machine code. The code is generated to be not relocateable.

The language has been designed to allow other target platforms as well. For instance, there are implementations that compile Go code into Javascript and PHP.

It is not possible to use Go code in a shared library.

Comment: Can you maybe give some references so I can read more about it?

Comment: I guess gccgo with `-shared` can be used to build shared libraries with go.

Comment: @matthias krull While this is in principle true, the resulting shared library can only used by Go programs and it is not possible to use it with dlopen() or similar functions.